Why property A is called when ngModel is used but not linked to that property A?
Given the following testing example:
blank-counter.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blank-counter',
  templateUrl: './blank-counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blank-counter.component.css']
})
export class BlankCounterComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  constructor() { }
  currentDateTime = new Date();
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('blank counter ngOnInit()');
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('ngOnChanges, changes:'+changes);
  }

   //@Input() 
   _counterValue = 0; // notice the '_'  

  get counterValue() {
    console.log('get counterValue()');
    return this._counterValue;
  }
}

blank-counter.component.html
<p>blank-counter works!</p>
{{counterValue}}
<p>Input with ngModel:<input type="text" [ngModel]="abc"/></p>
<p>Input without ngModel:<input type="text" value="abc"/></p>
<p>Current Date Time:{{currentDateTime}}</p>

template-driven-form-ex2.component.html
<p>template-driven-form-ex2 works!</p>
<app-blank-counter name="blankCounter"></app-blank-counter>

template-driven-form-ex2.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-driven-form-ex2',
  templateUrl: './template-driven-form-ex2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template-driven-form-ex2.component.css']
})
export class TemplateDrivenFormEx2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  
}


If I type some text in

    <p>Input without ngModel:<input type="text" value="abc"/></p>

get counterValue() is not called, but if I type some text in
<p>Input with ngModel:<input type="text" [ngModel]="abc"/></p>

get counterValue() is called, why?
I know [ngModel] cause template flow to component ts to copy the value to component property "abc" (although no this property defined in component), but why get counterValue() is also called?  is it due to the blank-counter.component.html is refreshed?

I found the ngOnchanges is not called even I type something in the textbox with [ngModel], why?

Also, when I type some text in the textbox with [ngModel], get counterValue() is called, then why


currentDateTime = new Date();

is not called? As I see the value of {{currentDateTime}} is never changed.

The ngModel directive is triggering the change detection on the ngModelDirective, this change detection triggered on the directive gets propagated to the parent app-blank-counter, hence you are seeing the console.log messages, this is my understanding from trial and error. Then also triggers change detection on the parent app-root
ng_model.ts - source code
import {
  Component,
  SimpleChanges,
  OnInit,
  OnChanges,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blank-counter',
  imports: [FormsModule],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
  <p>blank-counter works!</p>
  {{counterValue}}
  <p>Input with ngModel:<input type="text" [ngModel]="abc"/></p>
  <p>Input without ngModel:<input type="text" [value]="abc"/></p>
  <p>Current Date Time:{{currentDateTime}}</p>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class BlankCounterComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  abc!: string;
  constructor() {}
  currentDateTime = new Date();
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('blank counter ngOnInit()');
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('ngOnChanges, changes:' + changes);
  }

  //@Input()
  _counterValue = 0; // notice the '_'

  get counterValue() {
    console.log('get counterValue()');
    return this._counterValue;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BlankCounterComponent],
  template: `
    <p>template-driven-form-ex2 works!</p>
    <app-blank-counter name="blankCounter"></app-blank-counter>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngDoCheck(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('ngOnChanges parent, changes:' + changes);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Do you mean if I change any control in a child component with ngModel, it will trigger the child component and its parent component ngDoCheck? but then why ngDoCheck will trigger the get XXX() function? and why ngOnChanges is not triggered?

@user1169587 ngOnChanges -> will trigger on load and on all changes of @Input binding, so it should not trigger. get counterValue is a function that when used in the DOM will trigger on every change detection cycle, whenever the property is evaluated the getter is called. ngDoCheck does not call get counterValue method, since you used in the HTML, change detection calls it to get the latest value on each change detection cycle, if you use signals, you won't have this problem.
